# R's sandwich package producing strange results for robust standard errors in linear model

Tags: r, linear-regression, standard-error, robust

I am trying to find heteroskedasticity-robust standard errors in R, and most solutions I find are to use the `coeftest` and `sandwich` packages. However, when I use those packages, they seem to produce queer results (they're *way* too significant). Both my professor and I agree that the results don't look right. Could someone please tell me where my mistake is? Am I using the right package? Does the package have a bug in it? What should I use instead? Or can you reproduce the same results in STATA?

(The data is CPS data from 2010 to 2014, March samples. I created a MySQL database to hold the data and am using the `survey` package to help analyze it.)

Thank you in advance. (I have abridged the code somewhat to make it easier to read; let me know if you need to see more.)

```
>male.nat.reg <- svyglm(log(HOURWAGE) ~ AGE + I(AGE^2) + ... + OVERWORK, subset(fwyrnat2010.design, FEMALE == 0))

>summary(male.nat.reg)

Call:
NextMethod(formula = "svyglm", design)

Survey design:
subset(fwyrnat2010.design, FEMALE == 0)

Coefficients:
           Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   1.599e+00  6.069e-02  26.350  < 2e-16 ***
AGE           4.030e-02  3.358e-03  12.000  < 2e-16 ***
I(AGE^2)     -4.131e-04  4.489e-05  -9.204 9.97e-16 ***
NOHSDEG      -1.730e-01  1.281e-02 -13.510  < 2e-16 ***
ASSOC         1.138e-01  1.256e-02   9.060 2.22e-15 ***
SOMECOLL      5.003e-02  9.445e-03   5.298 5.11e-07 ***
BACHELOR      2.148e-01  1.437e-02  14.948  < 2e-16 ***
GRADUATE      3.353e-01  3.405e-02   9.848  < 2e-16 ***
INMETRO       3.879e-02  9.225e-03   4.205 4.93e-05 ***
NCHILDOLD     1.374e-02  4.197e-03   3.273 0.001376 ** 
NCHILDYOUNG   2.334e-02  6.186e-03   3.774 0.000247 ***
NOTWHITE     -5.026e-02  8.583e-03  -5.856 3.92e-08 ***
MARRIED      -8.226e-03  1.531e-02  -0.537 0.592018    
NEVERMARRIED -4.644e-02  1.584e-02  -2.932 0.004009 ** 
NOTCITIZEN   -6.759e-02  1.574e-02  -4.295 3.47e-05 ***
STUDENT      -1.231e-01  1.975e-02  -6.231 6.52e-09 ***
VET           3.336e-02  1.751e-02   1.905 0.059091 .  
INUNION       2.366e-01  1.271e-02  18.614  < 2e-16 ***
PROFOCC       2.559e-01  1.661e-02  15.413  < 2e-16 ***
TSAOCC        9.997e-02  1.266e-02   7.896 1.27e-12 ***
FFFOCC        2.076e-02  2.610e-02   0.795 0.427859    
PRODOCC       2.164e-01  1.281e-02  16.890  < 2e-16 ***
LABOROCC      6.074e-02  1.253e-02   4.850 3.60e-06 ***
AFFIND        6.834e-02  2.941e-02   2.324 0.021755 *  
MININGIND     3.034e-01  3.082e-02   9.846  < 2e-16 ***
CONSTIND      1.451e-01  1.524e-02   9.524  < 2e-16 ***
MANUFIND      1.109e-01  1.393e-02   7.963 8.80e-13 ***
UTILIND       1.422e-01  1.516e-02   9.379 3.78e-16 ***
WHOLESALEIND  2.884e-02  1.766e-02   1.633 0.104910    
FININD        6.215e-02  2.084e-02   2.983 0.003436 ** 
BUSREPIND     6.588e-02  1.755e-02   3.753 0.000266 ***
SERVICEIND    5.412e-02  2.403e-02   2.252 0.026058 *  
ENTERTAININD -1.192e-01  3.060e-02  -3.896 0.000159 ***
PROFIND       1.536e-01  1.854e-02   8.285 1.55e-13 ***
OVERWORK      6.738e-02  1.007e-02   6.693 6.59e-10 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for gaussian family taken to be 0.1367476)

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 2

>coeftest(male.nat.reg, vcov = vcovHC(male.nat.reg, type = 'HC0'))

z test of coefficients:

                Estimate  Std. Error   z value  Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)   1.5992e+00  9.7176e-08  16456481 < 2.2e-16 ***
AGE           4.0296e-02  5.4766e-09   7357823 < 2.2e-16 ***
I(AGE^2)     -4.1314e-04  7.3222e-11  -5642330 < 2.2e-16 ***
NOHSDEG      -1.7305e-01  1.4431e-08 -11991482 < 2.2e-16 ***
ASSOC         1.1378e-01  1.4248e-08   7985751 < 2.2e-16 ***
SOMECOLL      5.0035e-02  9.9689e-09   5019088 < 2.2e-16 ***
BACHELOR      2.1476e-01  2.0588e-08  10430993 < 2.2e-16 ***
GRADUATE      3.3533e-01  8.3327e-08   4024301 < 2.2e-16 ***
INMETRO       3.8790e-02  8.9666e-09   4326013 < 2.2e-16 ***
NCHILDOLD     1.3738e-02  5.2244e-09   2629554 < 2.2e-16 ***
NCHILDYOUNG   2.3344e-02  5.5405e-09   4213300 < 2.2e-16 ***
NOTWHITE     -5.0261e-02  1.0150e-08  -4951908 < 2.2e-16 ***
MARRIED      -8.2263e-03  1.8867e-08   -436026 < 2.2e-16 ***
NEVERMARRIED -4.6440e-02  1.7847e-08  -2602096 < 2.2e-16 ***
NOTCITIZEN   -6.7594e-02  2.4446e-08  -2765080 < 2.2e-16 ***
STUDENT      -1.2306e-01  3.2514e-08  -3785014 < 2.2e-16 ***
VET           3.3356e-02  3.0996e-08   1076125 < 2.2e-16 ***
INUNION       2.3659e-01  1.7786e-08  13301699 < 2.2e-16 ***
PROFOCC       2.5594e-01  2.2177e-08  11540563 < 2.2e-16 ***
TSAOCC        9.9971e-02  1.6707e-08   5983922 < 2.2e-16 ***
FFFOCC        2.0762e-02  2.3625e-08    878801 < 2.2e-16 ***
PRODOCC       2.1638e-01  1.3602e-08  15907683 < 2.2e-16 ***
LABOROCC      6.0741e-02  1.3445e-08   4517854 < 2.2e-16 ***
AFFIND        6.8342e-02  3.2895e-08   2077563 < 2.2e-16 ***
MININGIND     3.0343e-01  3.2948e-08   9209326 < 2.2e-16 ***
CONSTIND      1.4512e-01  2.1871e-08   6635457 < 2.2e-16 ***
MANUFIND      1.1094e-01  1.9636e-08   5649569 < 2.2e-16 ***
UTILIND       1.4216e-01  2.0930e-08   6792029 < 2.2e-16 ***
WHOLESALEIND  2.8842e-02  1.8662e-08   1545525 < 2.2e-16 ***
FININD        6.2147e-02  2.8214e-08   2202691 < 2.2e-16 ***
BUSREPIND     6.5883e-02  2.7866e-08   2364269 < 2.2e-16 ***
SERVICEIND    5.4118e-02  2.4758e-08   2185907 < 2.2e-16 ***
ENTERTAININD -1.1922e-01  2.9474e-08  -4044852 < 2.2e-16 ***
PROFIND       1.5364e-01  3.0132e-08   5098879 < 2.2e-16 ***
OVERWORK      6.7376e-02  1.0981e-08   6135525 < 2.2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `sandwich` package is object-oriented and essentially relies on two methods being available: `estfun()` and `bread()`, see the package vignettes for more details. For objects of class `svyglm` these methods are not available but as `svyglm` objects inherit from `glm` the `glm` methods are found and used. I suspect that this leads to incorrect results in the survey context though, possibly by a weighting factor or so. I'm not familiar enough with the `survey` package to provide a workaround. The `survey` maintainer might be able to say more... Hope that helps.