# Does the Sandwich Package work for Robust Standard Errors for Logistic Regression with basic Survey Weights

Tags: r, logistic-regression, survey, standard-error, robust

I am running logistic regressions with a panel data set from survey data and I want to correct the standard errors for the panel design. The weights included in this survey account for sampling probability, panel mortality and post stratification.

If I understood [Berger et al 2017](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sandwich/vignettes/sandwich-CL.pdf) correctly I should use clustered covariances for panel data. However, I am not sure if the commands work for data with survey weights.

I started by estimating the regressions with `glm` and correcting the standard errors with `coeftest` from the `lmtest` package and `vcovPL` from the `sandwich`package. Subsequently, I used `svydesign` and `svyglm` from the `survey` package to estimate a weighted model and corrected the standard errors again the same way.

In this Question [R's sandwich package producing strange results for robust standard errors in linear model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28828381/rs-sandwich-package-producing-strange-results-for-robust-standard-errors-in-lin) Zeileis writes that using `svyglm` objects might produce incorrect results. However, I am not sure if this applies only for complex survey weight (with strata etc.) or as well for basic survey weights, since its pointed out [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/57107/use-of-weights-in-svyglm-vs-glm) that without the use of strata there is not much difference. However, I don't fully understand the explanation there. Moreover, I wonder if the newly implemented features described in [Berger et al 2017](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sandwich/vignettes/sandwich-CL.pdf) allow for using a `svyglm` object. So I don't know if I can use the commands in the `sandwich` package for objects of class `svyglm` if my design has no strata.

Here is the code I used:

```
# not weighted
model <- glm(depend_var ~ indep_var1 + indep_var2 ,family=quasibinomial(link='logit'),data=dataset)
m_vcov <- coeftest(model,vcov. =  sandwich::vcovPL(x = model, cluster = ~ id_var,order.by = ~ year ,pairwise = T))

# weighted
design.ps <- svydesign(ids=~1, weights=~wgt, data=dataset)
model_wgt <- svyglm(depend_var ~ indep_var1 + indep_var2, design=design.ps,family=quasibinomial(link='logit'),data=dataset)
mwt_vcov <- coeftest(model_wgt, vcov. = sandwich::vcovPL(x = model_wgt, cluster = ~ id_var,order.by = ~ year ,pairwise = T))
```

Looking at the coefficients provided by the test code above, the results seem kind of reasonable unlike the results provided here: [R's sandwich package producing strange results for robust standard errors in linear model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28828381/rs-sandwich-package-producing-strange-results-for-robust-standard-errors-in-lin)

```
# basic model
> summary(model)
                  Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)       -3.68570    0.01264 -291.68   <2e-16 ***
indep_var1_test    0.37538    0.01111   33.78   <2e-16 ***
indep_var2_test    1.05226    0.01100   95.62   <2e-16 ***

# basic model with SE correction
> m_vcov
                   Estimate Std. Error  z value  Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)       -3.685702   0.176121 -20.9271 < 2.2e-16 ***
indep_var1_test    0.375380   0.049817   7.5353 4.874e-14 ***
indep_var2_test    1.052258   0.068763  15.3027 < 2.2e-16 ***

# weighted model 
> summary(model_wgt)
                  Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)       -3.89702    0.01751 -222.57   <2e-16 ***
indep_var1_test    0.42373    0.01454   29.15   <2e-16 ***
indep_var2_test    1.05291    0.01439   73.15   <2e-16 ***

# weighted model with SE correction
> mwt_vcov
                   Estimate Std. Error  z value  Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)       -3.897021   0.319932 -12.1808 < 2.2e-16 ***
indep_var1_test.   0.423732   0.075202   5.6346 1.755e-08 ***
indep_var2_test    1.052915   0.126569   8.3189 < 2.2e-16 ***
```

My question is: Can I use the commands above to correct the standard errors?

I guess my question is similar to this unanswered one: 
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/260515/does-coeftest-correctly-use-weights-from-svydesign-in-svyglm-object?rq=1

Comment: This is the guy that would know <https://notstatschat.rbind.io/>

Comment: Thanks. If no one answers, I'll write to him.

Answer (score 7):

You want to use

```
coeftest(model, vcov=vcov(model))
```

For `svyglm` models, `vcov()` already produces the appropriate sandwich estimator, and I don't think the "sandwich" package knows enough about the internals of the object to get it right.